# Recursive function mapped onto list

Tags: recursion, map

I want to create a table of values, and the values are defined recursively as follows:
$$
 b_{t,m} = \begin{cases}
 b_{t+1,m} + b_{t+1,m-1}\delta^{t-T} & \text{ if } t \in \{2,\ldots,T-1\} \text{ and } m \in \{2,\ldots,T-t+1\} \\
 %
 1 & \text{ if } t\in \{2,\ldots,T\} \text{ and } m = 1  \\
 %
 0 & \text{ otherwise }
 \end{cases}
$$

I need to create the table for $t=\{1,\ldots,T\}$ and $m=\{1,\ldots,T\}$
I'm new to Mathematica, and trying to accomplish this by mapping a recursive function over a list. My current attempt is as follows:

```
Clear[capT, delta, indexTable, bFunc, bMat]
capT = 3;

bFunc[{t_Integer, 1}] /; 2 <= t <= capT = 1;

bFunc[{t_Integer, m_Integer}] /; 
  m < 1 || m > capT - t + 1 || ( 
    1 <= m <= capT - t + 1  && (t < 2 || t > capT - 1)) = 0;

bFunc[{t_Integer, m_Integer}]  /; 
  2 <= t <= capT - 1 && 2 <= m <= capT - t + 1 := 
 bFunc[{t, m}] = 
  bFunc[{t + 1, m}] + bFunc[{t + 1, m - 1}]*delta^(t - capT)

indexTable = Reverse[Table[{t, m}, {t, 1, capT, 1}, {m, 1, capT, 1}]];
bMat = Map[bFunc, indexTable, 2]
```

Which produces the following output

```
{bFunc[{1, 0, 0}], bFunc[{1, 1/delta, 0}], bFunc[{0, 0, 0}]}
```

I must be missing something. This approach partially works, because all the values I need are there, but they are wrapped inside of additional function calls. The output that I want to have would look like

```
{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1/delta, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

What am I not seeing?

Comment: You want to feed each of the ordered pairs of that list of lists (`indexTable`) to `bfunc`? Then: `bMat = Map[bFunc, indexTable, {2}]`, because you want to `Map` *only* at Level 2. Without the braces, it tries to map at both levels 1 and 2.

Comment: yes! That was it. Thanks!